# HMS IAP has no renewal event after I cancel the subscription

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, huawei-developers, huawei-mobile-services

I noticed that I did not receive the renewal event after I restore a canceled subscription. Here are the steps that I made:

- create a new subscription - received `INITIAL_BUY event`.
- received `RENEWAL` event a few minutes later.
- canceled subscription through API and received `RENEWAL_STOPPED`.
- bought the same subscription again and received `RENEWAL_RESTORED` and `INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL` events but there is no `RENEWAL` event received after that.

I have two questions:

- How can I determine that the subscription is in grace period by data from `InAppPurchaseDetails`?
- Could anyone tell me what went wrong as I was able to reproduce this behavior several times in Sandbox mode.

Comment: @Zinna's answer is clear. Here is the docs ```graceExpirationTime``` [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References-V1/inapppurchasedata-0000001050725664-V1#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050725664__section745539123414) Obtains timestamp when a grace period ends.

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox test subscription is performed differently compare with the real SW behavior. When the previously canceled subscription is resumed, the sandbox environment simulates charging only once and does not simulate renewal. Therefore, the notification of key subscription events is normal. This is not the case in the real world.

In `InAppPurchaseDetails`, the `graceExpirationTime` field indicates the expiration time of the grace period.

More information regarding HMS IAP subscription [Here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/subscription-functions-0000001050130264)

And the info. regarding HMS AG sandbox testing is at [Here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/sandbox-testing-0000001050035039)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thanks for pointing it out.